# Unable to Access Public Variables - Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel-2010

I am working on a rather large Excel application via VBA. I want to place all my public variables in one module. Then I would assign and use those variables in my other modules in the same workbook. Here's what I have.

```
Option Explicit

Public wdApp As Word.Application
Public wdDoc As Word.Document
```

But when I tried to assign those variables in my other modules, I got the following message. Shouldn't public variables be accessible to all modules? What
am I missing?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the concept of *objects*, which are *instances* of a **class module**.

I'm betting my shirt that you've written that code in a class module (note, `ThisWorkbook` and `Sheet42` modules *are* class modules).

Add a new **standard module** (.bas), and move your global/public variables there.

In order to access the public members of a **class module**, you need to `New` up an instance of that class first.

Comment: You're right. I had it as `class module`. A slip of my hand.

Answer (score 1):

The declarations need to be in a **standard module**, not in any of the worksheet/workbook/class modules, otherwise they are treated as public properties of a class (namely the worksheet, workbook, or class).